# Relación de tablas

Tags: base-de-datos, ddd

Estoy diseñando una solución en la que tengo una entidad Ciudad y Ruta en la cual Ruta tiene dos propiedades que no se como relacionarlas(Origen y Destino).
[image: Ruta]

Origen esta relacionado con CiudadId esa es una relación y Destino también esta relacionado con CiudadId esa es la segunda relación, me parece logico.

Me pueden ayudar a exclarecer este tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la mejor solución sería:

- Doble `JOIN` de la tabla `ciudad` con la tabla `ruta`: uno apuntando al `origen` y otro al `destino`
- Un `JOIN` simple de `ruta` con `recorrido` mediante la clave `ruta_id`.

Te dejo aquí un ejemplo funcionando.

Es un ejemplo mínimo el cual puedes adaptar a tus necesidades, agregando filtros, agrupaciones, ordenando, etc.

---

### [Demo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2d330/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ciudad
    (`ciudad_id` int, `ciudad_nom` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO ciudad
    (`ciudad_id`, `ciudad_nom`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Madrid'),
    (2, 'Sevilla'),
    (3, 'Vigo')
;

CREATE TABLE ruta
    (`ruta_id` int, `origen` int, `destino` int, `km` float)
;

INSERT INTO ruta
    (`ruta_id`, `origen`, `destino`, `km`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2, 100.40),
    (2, 2, 3, 120.10),
    (3, 3, 2, 109.00),
    (4, 2, 1, 140.15);

CREATE TABLE recorrido
    (`recorrido_id` int, `ruta_id` int, `galones` float)
;    

INSERT INTO recorrido
    (`recorrido_id`, `ruta_id`, `galones`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 50.40),
    (2, 2, 60.05),
    (3, 3, 54.50),
    (4, 4, 70.08);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  ru.ruta_id, co.ciudad_nom as origen, cd.ciudad_nom as destino,
  ru.km, re.galones
FROM
  ruta ru
  LEFT JOIN ciudad co ON ru.origen = co.ciudad_id
  LEFT JOIN ciudad cd ON ru.destino = cd.ciudad_id
  LEFT JOIN recorrido re ON ru.ruta_id = re.ruta_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2d330/1/0)**:

```
| ruta_id | origen     | destino    |     km | galones |
|---------|------------|------------|--------|---------|
|       1 |     Madrid |    Sevilla |  100.4 |    50.4 |
|       2 |    Sevilla |       Vigo |  120.1 |   60.05 |
|       3 |       Vigo |    Sevilla |    109 |    54.5 |
|       4 |    Sevilla |     Madrid | 140.15 |   70.08 |
```

Comment: sería una sola relación?

Comment: @PedroÁvila No entendí la pregunta. En la respuesta explico que incluirías la tabla ciudad dos veces, una para el origen y otra para el destino. No sé si te refieres a eso.

Comment: Dicho de otra manera como sería la relación entre esas dos tablas Ciudad y Ruta

Comment: @PedroÁvila Si te fijas en la **Query 1** la relación se establece usando los campos `origen` y `destino` de la tabla `ruta` y relacionándolos con el campo `ciudad_id` de la tabla `ciudad`. Analiza la Query 1: `...   LEFT JOIN ciudad co ON ru.origen = co.ciudad_id
  LEFT JOIN ciudad cd ON ru.destino = cd.ciudad_id
...` Lo que uso después de los nombres de tablas son _alias_, es como si usara `AS`, es  para hacer la sentencia más entendible. Por ejemplo: `ciudad co` sería igual a `ciudad AS co` y uso `co` como abreviatura de _ciudad de origen_

Comment: Si es así la relación que muestro en mi imagen esta bien.

Comment: @PedroÁvila Claro, la relación está bien y el código lo demuestra. Puedes obtener todos los datos de cualquier ruta aplicando los `JOIN` de esa manera.

Comment: Mi pregunta se enfoca en el diseño no en hacer la consulta

Comment: @PedroÁvila La respuesta es: **el diseño está bien** y tienes una consulta que lo prueba. La prueba de un diseño bien hecho es que no tengas problemas al consultar la BD y obtener los datos adecuadamente y de forma optimizada. Si la respuesta no responde a tu inquietud, plantéala de otra manera o esperemos que alguien más te responda amigo, yo doy por concluido el asunto. Saludos.

Comment: El tema es que estoy usando power designer y cuando mando a chequear el diseño me da error que en Ruta role name uniqueness

Comment: @PedroÁvila No conozco Powerdesigner ni sé como funciona, pero un diseño como el que presentas ese es el tipo de relación adecuado, quizá el error se deba a que le estás dando el mismo nombre a ambas relaciones... no lo sé. Si te fijas en los JOIN verás que en cada uno la tabla ciudad tiene un alias distinto, porque en realidad el manejador de BD la usa dos veces para determinar el origen y el destino. Quizá sea un problema de nombre de relaciones, en PD... no te puedo decir porque no lo conozco.

Comment: No crees que es una relación muchos a muchos entre RecorridoVehiculo y Rutas

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que debería haber una relación M:M entre esas dos tablas?

Comment: Si me parece, aunque son rutas definidas

Comment: Creo que tienes demasiado elementos **variables** en `RecorridoVehiculo` como para hacer con ella una relación M:M, si consideras que por algún motivo debe ser así, todos esos elementos **variables** deberían ir en otra tabla. No le veo mucho sentido porque además en una misma ruta, en días diversos, se pueden recorrer más kilómetros por algún motivo (ejemplo que el día x hubo que desviarse porque una carretera estaba cerrada), variaría también la cantidad de galones consumidos, etc. No veo que sea una solución viable.